# Codeigniter on OpenShift is redirecting to 404 error page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, openshift

I have recently created an account on OpenShift to host some of my applications and send them to my clients, so they can see, test and give me feedbacks.

My first application is a CodeIgniter project that I had on my computer. I created a default controller called `tester` and set it on `routes.php`.

I configured my .htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|styles)
RewriteCond $1 !\.(ico|js|css|jpg|png|gif|html|ico?g)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

It works fine on localhost, but it is redirecting me to the 404 page all the time when I try to see my website on OpenShift.

How can I test what route is being traced by Codeigniter? Any of you have any clue about what is happening?

Comment: use firebug and see where it is been redirected

Comment: hey. i usually use chrome. i installed firebug on firefox, opened it and refreshed the page. where I am supposed to look for this?

Comment: there is a tab named `net` click all and check there

Comment: alright. it says `GET app-namespace.rhcloud.com` (app and namespace is the actual name of my application and my domain on openshift)

Comment: have u set your `$config['base_url'] to ''` gimme the link of your website..

Comment: http://lavile-asterixestudio.rhcloud.com/
this is the error codeigniter responds. so it's not redirecting to the correct action or controller I guess. and yes `$config['base_url'] = '';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80541/discussion-between-ghostman-and-victor-ferreira).

Answer (score 0):

use this.

in **config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

in **Config/routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";//your controller name. ex: i used main
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

in **controller folder**

> File name  = **main.php**

**inside main.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller
{

    public function  __construct()
    {


    }
}
```

in **.htaccess**(out side application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: whats your site URL??

Comment: lavile-asterixestudio.rhcloud.com

Comment: what is your default controller name??

Comment: it's tester. it has an index action that echoes 'hello world'